# Retrieve data from the first td in every tr

Tags: php, screen-scraping, simple-html-dom

I'm scraping a page which contains of a table with several tr's. Inside every tr there's four td's, and I want to get the data from the first of these td's. Below is the code I've tried so far, but it grabs all the td's. How can I accomplish what I want?

```
...
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html = file_get_html($url);

foreach($html->find('table tr') as $row) {
    foreach($row->find('td', 0) as $cell) {
        echo $cell;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show some html next time for a +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about why you're using the second `foreach` when you actually only mean to act on one element within each `row`.

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html = file_get_html($url);

foreach($html->find('table tr') as $row) {
    $cell = $row->find('td', 0);
    echo $cell;
}
```

Comment: No problem. You can also do `$cells = $html->find('table tr')->find('td', 0)` in one fell swoop, and I think `$cells` will end up as an array of all the first td elements that you can just dump out however you see fit. (BTW, kindly mark as accepted? Thanks!)

Answer (score 1):

simple html dom is a turd. It's simpler to use the built in dom functions and xpath:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

foreach($xpath->query('//td[1]') as $td){
  echo $td->nodeValue;
}
```

That said, [I would probably still prefer to use phpquery](http://scraperblog.blogspot.com/2012/11/choosing-php-html-parser.html)